# Не могу изменить CSS стили в wordpress ошибка первой строки

Tags: wordpress

Не могу изменить CSS стили. Ошибка  в первой строке кода. Пробелы удалил, не знаю как еще решить.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\notes\wp-content\themes\test\functions.php:1) in W:\domains\notes\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1195
```

вот код functions.php

```
<?php

   function learningCode(){
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'learningCode');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Пробелы удалил, не знаю как еще решить.

Сохранить functions.php (и все др. файлы которые правились) в UTF-8 **без [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

Comment: спасибо вам большое